# Add comma after each number in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a simple page that prompts the user for an input and checks a list to see if that input is included and will then return a true or false answer to the user. At the moment it is working fine and the code looks like this:

```
var barcodes = [
    123425245,
    62753264574,
    1878769047,
    00000000000001718075,
    302,
    303,
];

var entry=prompt("enter barcode");
var num1=parseInt(entry);
document.write(barcodes.includes(num1));
```

My problem is that I have over 2000 items to add to this array and I am trying to copy and paste them in from an excel spreadsheet. When I copy them in there is no comma separating  each barcode and therefore i'm getting an error message. Is there a quick way to add commas at the end of each number in the array or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is not a js related question. You should look into editor like notepad++ which helps you in these situations.

Comment: This has more to do with your code editor and not that much with javascript. Try a find & replace of all white-space/line-break characters and replace them with `,`.

Comment: Try string concatenation in Excel and then paste result in your code

Comment: The concatenation worked perfectly, thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

You can create an array using `split()` by splitting your data like this:

```js
let str = "123425245 62753264574 1878769047 00000000000001718075 302 303";

let barcodes = str.split(" ").map(Number);

console.log(barcodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var barcodes = [
    123425245,
    62753264574,
    1878769047,
    00000000000001718075,
    302,
    303,
];

var temp = barcodes.join(",");
console.log(temp)
```